# How to add and bind a cs file to an ASCX/ASPX page that doesn't alrady have one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I know silly question but i tried looking it up on Google with no luck.

Comment: Are you going from a single file (i.e. inline code) to a code-beside file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `Inherits` attribute to your `<@Page` directive with the name of the class represented in the cs file. For example:

```
<@Page ... Inherits="MyNamespace.MyCustomPage">
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jason has already answered, also put a "CodeFile=anycodefile.cs" in the page directive. 
 

     `<@Page ... Inherits="MyNamespace.MyCustomPage" CodeFile="MyCustomPage.cs">`

If your page has a code-behind file, use the CodeFile attribute. Otherwise put the assembly containing the code behind class in the bin folder and use the inherits. The class must derive from webpage or usercontrol and must be public.